# How to edit a read-only archive?

Tags: read-only, archive

I have an archive type supported by file-roller and the properties for it have NOT been set to read-only. When I open it, however, I am unable to modify its contents as the file appears to be read-only. Is there a way to fix this? It's only for this archive which I find strange.

Comment: Do you have to use `sudo`? There are also other programs you can use to set a file so that even `root` cannot change a file, and you have to go back to that program and change the file back to read-only. Could you have used one of those on accident?

Comment: Not all archives support write access. It would tremedously help if you told us what archive format this was.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of info, but...

1. extract the file you want to modify to your hard disk, in a folder. Let suppose you extract it in the folder `myfold` under your home directory. Let's say the file is called `myfile.txt`.
2. Open a terminal, do:

   `cd ~/myfold`

   `chmod +w myfile.txt`
3. Now you can navigate to that folder and open the file in read/write mode.